# Suggested solutions on "Data source name not found" not working

Tags: php, ms-access, pdo, xampp

my title seems a very common problem and been asked a lot. However, I tried every suggestions found in the net but I'm still having this error. So here are the details:

I'm using ms access for my database, php, html, xampp. My laptop is running 64 bit OS. 
[image]

[image]
First thing I tried is removing the DSN under User DSN. But it still doesn't work. Per checking of my phpinfo(), the following PDO drivers were installed: odbc, mysql, and sqlite.

[image]

I also restarted my server and this laptop for a number of times already.

I also installed MS Access Drive (64 bit). I tried installing the 32 bit to no avail since I'm using 64 bit.

So my question is, are there any other ways to solve this data source name issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those encountering the same problem, I resolved this issue by installing Microsoft Access Driver 32-bit. However, in order to do that, I uninstalled first my Microsoft Office 64 bit. That's all. Happy coding!